# Why can I use Maybe with record syntax, but not regular ADT syntax?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I'm writing some data types in Haskell to represent formal English grammar.

```
data S = NP VP
```

So far so good, a sentence is just a noun phrase and a verb phrase. Marvel at the elegant beauty of algebraic data types!

I'll also define a determiner and adjective as:

```
data D = A | An | The
type Adj = String -- Too many adjectives for me to list, so I make it a type
                  -- synonym for String.
```

Now, I'm having issues defining NP, which is a noun with an optional determiner and adjective. My first natural instinct is to use Maybe:

```
data NP = Maybe D Maybe Adj N
```

which gives me the error:

```
Expecting one more argument to `Maybe' In the type `Maybe' In the definition of data 
constructor `Maybe' In the data type declaration for `NP'
```

(Note that the error doesn't change based on whether or not I have imported Data.Maybe)

The only way I ever got this to work was by using record syntax:

```
data NP' = NP' {determiner :: Maybe D, adjective :: Maybe Adj, noun :: N}
```

Why does this only work when I use record syntax?

Comment: The first identifier in each declaration is the name of the constructor. `data S = NP VP` has one constructor called `NP` which contains a value of type `VP`. You probably want `data S = S NP VP`, which is a constructor called `S` containing a value of type `NP` and a value of of type `VP`.

Comment: Also, these are not abstract datatypes, they are concrete datatypes. Perhaps you meant *algebraic* data types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
data NP = NP (Maybe D) (Maybe Adj) N
```

You need to

1. Begin with a constructor name: in this case `NP`
2. Apply only a single argument to `Maybe` which I've done by disambiguating it with parentheses
3. Denote 3 separate slots in the constructor, one for each component type

Comment: Why do you need to begin with the constructor name in this instance?

`data VP = V (Maybe Adv)` is legal, so why not `data NP = (Maybe D) (Maybe Adj) N`? (with `type V = String`)

Comment: @Sintrastes, it's how the data is constructed. After this declaration, a function will be introduced `NP :: Maybe D -> Maybe Adj -> N -> NP`, which is how you construct objects of type `NP`.  You need a constructor name because (like `Maybe`) data types are allowed to have multiple constructors, so we need to say which one we mean.

Comment: @Sintrastes `data VP = V (Maybe Abv)` does NOT define a VP as a V and maybe an Abv.  It says that a VP is the `V` constructor applied to maybe a Abv; i.e. it doesn't contain a V, only (maybe) an Adv.  That almost certainly *not* what you want.

Comment: @Sintrastes To clarify the previous comment: `data VP = V (Maybe Adv)` with `type V = String` works because type constructors and data constructors are in two different namespaces. I.e. the first `V` has nothing to do with the second `V`, despite having the same name. Your confusion may arise from the common custom of giving a data type's type constructor and data constructor the same name when there is only one of the latter.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you meant to write (with the `NP` data constructor):

```
data NP = NP Maybe D Maybe Adj N
```

In your example, `NP` is being defined as a constructor with 5 arguments, the first of which is a bare "`Maybe`". This doesn't work because `Maybe` is a type that needs one type parameter, which is what the error message is telling you.

To get your desired interpretation, you need to surround the `Maybe _`s with parentheses:

```
data NP = NP (Maybe D) (Maybe Adj) N
```